# Can you generalize Feynman diagrams to 2-dimensional CW-complexes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, feynman-diagrams

Feynman diagrams (for just a typical run-of-the-mill QFT) are graphs, and it recently occurred to me that that means they are 1-dimensional CW-complexes; in particular, they are connected 1-dimensional CW-complexes of "homogeneous dimension" (in the sense that there aren't any lone 0-dimensional pieces hanging around). Can one generalize this? That is, can we write down some generalization of QFT, where, instead of Feynman diagrams, we have connected 2-dimensional CW-complexes of "homogeneous dimension" (now meaning that there aren't any 1D "hairs" flying off)?

I know that string theory accomplishes this to a limited degree. In that case, Feynman diagrams are replaced by smooth 2D surfaces, which naturally have a CW-complex structure. However, I am asking if one can do this with general connected 2-dimensional CW-complexes that may not necessarily be smooth manifolds.

Comment: It's unclear to me what this should mean. Feynman diagrams are just a graphical representation of terms in a perturbative expansion (really a Taylor series). It's just notation.

Comment: This is a common viewpoint for thinking about perturbative QFT; the niceness of string theory is often motivated by noting that the fact that string diagrams are smooth manifolds means there are no point-like singular spots, and one can say that string theory simply upgrades QFT from graphs to Riemann surfaces.

Comment: I guess to be more clear, my question is whether such a generalization exists. That is, whether there is a theory that naturally is expressed (perturbatively) in terms of 2-dimensional CW-complexes, rather than graphs. If I was only concerned with drawing pictures, I could just slap on a name and call it a day.

Comment: I should also point out that even in string theory, the genus expansion you're referring to is still nothing more than a perturbative expansion, it's simply a different one than in QFT because the conformal symmetry allows us to consider the partition function in fixed genus sector non-perturbatively. So I would tend to say, without some information about what such CW-complexes would mean, your question is essentially whether there exists a framework in which such notation might make sense.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could likely consider any p-Brane theory (like a generalization of strings to higher dimensional surfaces) and then speak of an expansion of the partition function in terms of a sum over appropriate dimensional surfaces. But you would like the power of 2d conformal symmetry to really make this particularly useful I think. But I am also not an expert on these things.

Comment: Perhaps my knowledge of branes is a bit weak, but I thought the perturbative expansion for D$p$-branes for any $p>0$ would consist of smooth ($p+1$)-dimensional manifolds. But that is precisely what I do not want; I want something that has 2d CW-complexes that aren't smooth manifolds. Otherwise, string theory would suffice.